# Casting the string column as int in hql query or criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Can anyone guide me where i am going wrong? Its giving zero result but in db values are existing as for condition appear in the below query.

```
  Str = QueryImpl(from ArcZipCodeRange where cast(fromZip as int) >='12345' and cast(toZip as int)<='12345')
        arcZipCodeRangeList = 0
```

Comment: Why you do not use criteria?

Comment: can u give me example, how i can use this with criteria?please

Comment: Can anyone please add comments on this.

Comment: Please give detailed information what you want to do

Comment: well... i have a string property in a table and i need to compare it with an integer for both above columns fromZip  and toZip.

Comment: By casting to integer.

Comment: but you compare it with Strings

Comment: Also the posted code seems to be missing quotes around the actual hql query

Comment: Also the posted code seems to be missing quotes around the actual hql query

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure your conditions are correct?

```
cast(fromZip as int) >='12345' and cast(toZip as int)<='12345')
```

Would give all results with `from` > 12345 and `to` < 12345.

Should it be other way around:
`from` < 12345 and `to` > 12345?

Answer (score 2):

you are casting `fromZip` and `toZip` to an int and then compare it with a String. That is asking for trouble.

Use the same data type on both sides of the comparison.

Also as [@Fazovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30233559/66686) notes, your condition seems to be the wrong way round.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by `Hibernate Criteria` easily. For solution you must create your own `Hibernate Formula` for these(fromZip and toZip). The following must be your pojo mapping.

```
@Column
private String fromZip;

@Formula(value="to_number(fromZip)")
private double newfromZip;

@Column
private String toZip;

@Formula(value="to_number(toZip)")
private double newtoZip;
```

Following is your criteria for select:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ArcZipCodeRange.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("newfromZip", yourIntegerParameter));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("newtoZip", yourIntegerParameter));
List<ArcZipCodeRange> list = criteria.list();
```

I hope this will help you.